# How to close a window in python by name

Tags: python, taskkill, psutil

I'm making a minecraft console client script for a friend
It opens the console client based on a txt file

I figured out how to kill/terminate the window but this part doesn't physically close the window it just sets it to a normal command prompt window because it's created using a batch command

How would I close a program completely by name as if I pressed the "x" button in the top right hand corner of the application.

```
    os.system("taskkill /f /im MinecraftClient.exe")
 //for proc in psutil.process_iter():
   //  if proc.name() == "MinecraftClient.exe":
   //      proc.terminate()
   //      reap_children()
```

Neither of those actually closes the .exe it just changes it into a command prompt window. And I don't want to have to run through the for proc in psutil.process_iter() again just to close the command prompt windows.

**EDIT 1:**

How it opens the MinecraftClient.exe please keep in mind it is a console client that you download from github

```
def connect(file, directory, executeds):
with open(file) as file:
    for line in file:
        #stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE,
        lines = line.split(":")
        login = lines[0]
        password = lines[1]
        IP = lines[2]
    //     CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
   //      DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
        command = "MinecraftClient.exe {0} {1} {2}".format(login, password, IP)
        executed = Popen("start cmd /K " + command, cwd=directory, shell=True)
        out, err = executed.communicate()
        executeds.append(executed.pid)
        if executed.returncode == 0:
            print("Connected {0} to {1} successfully".format(login, IP))
        else:
            print("Failed to connect {0} to {1}.".format(login, IP))
            print("{0}".format(err))

        time.sleep(3)
```

Some things I'm not using because they were just tests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked, and I can't find anything called MinecraftClient.exe running for me. The Minecraft process is actually called `javaw.exe` - try killing that instead. If this is not the problem, I managed it with the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module as such:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("taskkill /f /im javaw.exe", shell=True)
```

`shell=True` prevents it from opening a command prompt on your screen.

**EDIT** 
Your screenshots show that it ends up becoming cmd.exe - try killing that instead?
Okay, after downloading the program I managed to successfully kill it using `subprocess.call('taskkill /f /im MinecraftClient.exe & taskkill /f /im cmd.exe', shell=True)`

Comment: MinecraftClient.exe is a downloaded app that is used to AFK farms on minecraft. I use a batch command starting it with cmd to open the .exe but when I close it it changes it to a regular old command prompt window so I don't want to have to add another os.system or for proc in psutil.process_iter() just to close the command prompt window also. I'll make an edit to show the connect function

Comment: the console client isn't handled by minecraft itself it's its own application that uses minecraft services to connect to minecraft servers. Just google minecraft console client it'll be the first github link

Comment: Forgot to mention the way you suggested it just changes it to a command prompt window as well.
This is what it's like after calling the close function
https://gyazo.com/ebbef76853328eef3c130cbb3da27e26
This is what it's like before calling the close function
https://gyazo.com/16eb61bbc8c84190c92d75ee7769a930
The very end of the image isn't supposed to be there because I just got kicked because I was on a VPN when logging in. But if I wasn't on a VPN it'll be like I was on the server but can't move.

Comment: Okay I wanted to avoid ending cmd itself but I guess I'll have to do it.

Comment: This blindly kills all instances of `cmd.exe`, not just the one which hosted the Minecraft client.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `psutil`, and `PyWin32` to kill or terminate 'cause it'll force exit the app during code execution. Since `MinecraftClient.exe` is a windows on the desktop you can use `psutil`, `win32gui`, `win32con`, and `win32process` to close it. `PostMessage` my throw permission denied error if Minecraft was launched from a higher privilege. If it does the try except will catch it and kill the process.

```py
from win32con import WM_CLOSE
from win32gui import EnumWindows, SendMessage
from win32process import GetWindowThreadProcessId
from psutil import Process


def enumerate_windows(hwnd, extra):
    _, pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    process = Process(pid = pid)
    if process.name() == 'MinecraftClient.exe':
        SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)
        if pid_exists(pid = pid):
            process.kill()


EnumWindows(enumerate_windows, None)
```

Comment: I added comments in each chunk of code to explain it's purpose and since you complained about the last two lines I removed them from my answer. The whole point of my answer was to show how you can "close" a window. Killing / terminating a window is the same as end task in task manager in windows.